# Was American Revolution a right-wing or left-wing movement?

Tags: united-states, history

I have thought about this issue many times for a few years, but I could never find a satisfying answer.

I tend to believe the American Revolution was a left-wing movement because it focused on the individual's rights rather than duties. But then the "founding fathers" were big on private property and gun ownership, which are right-wing issues. So, was the Revolution a hybrid movement?

And then, after 250 years, which political movement is the closest to the Revolutionaries?

Comment: Left and right are defined in terms of a country's modern politics. As such the question is anachronistic and likely primarily opinion based. I'm sure both major parties in the US today would like to claim they represent the true spirit of the founding fathers etc. There aren't much in the way of pro-British royalists left in the US, that's for sure.

Comment: Many of them fled: "In the end, many Loyalists simply left America. About 80,000 of them fled to Canada or Britain during or just after the war. Because Loyalists were often wealthy, educated, older, and Anglican, the American social fabric was altered by their departure." https://www.ushistory.org/us/11b.asp#:~:text=In%20the%20end%2C%20many%20Loyalists,was%20altered%20by%20their%20departure. Also worth reading about: [Black Loyalists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalist_(American_Revolution)#Slavery_and_Black_Loyalists).

Comment: By the way, Wikipedia article on anachronism has a nice link to [Translatio imperii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translatio_imperii) and how the claim to be the true inheritors of past greatness didn't escape much of the medieval historians. The fascists and nationalists (even the more benign ones) were very pretty late to this game.

Comment: If anything, the question might be better framed in terms of the opposition *progressives* or *liberals* vs. *conservatives* rather than *left wing* vs. *right wing*.

Answer (score 8):

The notion of "Left wing" and "Right wing" didn't exist in 1776 and modern notions of left and right can't be easily adapted to an 18th century political world.

The original meaning of left and right were the anti- and pro-monarchy factions in the National Assembly of France of 1789. By this notion the strongly republican nature of the American revolution was "left wing".

However you ask about "gun ownership" and "private property" and say that these are "right wing" - well perhaps they are in 2022.  But you can't put the standards of 2022 on people of 1776. That doesn't make sense. Indeed, gun ownership, in 1776, could be seen as a "radical left-wing" idea, in which the military would not be controlled by an aristocracy, but by a militia of farmers and smallholders.

In the years after the revolution, "slavery" was a "left wing" issue, because the Democratic party, representing particularly southern farmers, was strongly pro-slavery, and the Republican party was the party of emancipation.  Again, you can't put "left" and "right" labels on the people of the 18th century using  values of the 21st.

Similarly it doesn't make sense to ask "what current revolutionary movement is similar", because the context of the revolution (colonists rebelling against a monarchy) doesn't exist and can't exist today.

Comment: quibble: slavery is always illiberal and thus putatively rightist. Instead, we have to remember that parties swap orientations over time. In the era around the civil war Democrats were the conservative party and the (newly formed) Republican party was the Leftist (progressive) wing. Around the time of the New Deal this began to switch (in part because the definitions of 'liberal' and 'conservative' were shifting). The Dems began working on broad social reform issues and the Repubs began caterering to the wealthy and the morally indignant.

Comment: There should be a universal way to define left-wing and right-wing. We define monarchy and republic the same way Aristotle did, so this is doable.

Comment: @Blazkovitz Maybe L and R-wings can be universally defined, but the point is that gun ownership is not an inherently R-wing concept, just because it’s currently an R-wing talking point in the US. Look up Marx’s “Under no pretext” quote about arming the proletariat, an article of faith among modern leftist revolutionaries.

Comment: "There should be a universal way to define left-wing and right-wing."  On the contrary, Even within a single country at a single time, a simple scale from "left" to "right" is over-simplistic.  There are many dimensions of policy. Trying to fit one country's left right scale to another time is pointless.  For example, by the original definition, nearly all American politics is extreme left wing....  That doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @Blazkovitz We define those words that way because we choose to. The problem is that left and right wing have many meanings. As JamesK lays out, if you choose to stick with the original meanings of the words, then the answer is clear: the US revolution was a left-wing (meaning anti-monarchist) revolution, period. But, of course, we don’t use the words in the same way today, so it doesn’t answer the question you really want the answer to

Comment: @Ted, wrong. Liberal _is_ 'right' (vs 'left' as 'social'), this is how it's understood in most of the world. Slavery is nowhere on this scale, as it is, indeed, both illiberal and anti-social.

Comment: @Zeus: I shouldn't have to explain the different uses of the term 'liberal', or how it has evolved over time, and i dislike it when people are aggressive about their misperceptions. Go read [SEP on 'liberalism'](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/liberalism/), and then come back when you learn some manners.